# Will a clip-on zoom lens correct the distortion of a wide-angled smartphone lens?

Tags: distortion, smartphone

My friend wants to shoot a vlog style series and she doesn't currently own a DSLR, so she was going to shoot with her smartphone. I am aware of the natural distortion of features (noses, foreheads, etc.) that can occur with wider angle lenses, so she asked me about getting a clip on "telephoto" kit for her phone. That got me wondering...

> Does a zoom lens mounted on top of a wide angle lens correct any barrel distortion? Or simply magnify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You seem to confuse the distortion/accentuation that occurs with decreasing distance and the distortion that lenses have.**

Here's a very bad mockup of the scene:

[image: worst mockup ever]

<sup>**Legend:** Blue: *Camera*, Purple: *Subject*, Green: *Distance camera/subject (*`x`*)*, Orange: *Distance nose/ear (*`d`*)*</sup>

Consider this: When I stand around **200cm away** from you (`x`), the distance between the tip of your nose and your ears (`d`) is around 10cm, so **5% of the distance** me/you. When I stand around **50cm away** from you, the distance nose/ear is like **20% of the distance** me/you. Therefore, it has a much bigger impact on the picture - **with decreasing distance, people's faces (and other things) first appear "flattened", then will appear more plastic and then - when going at closer distances - features of the face will be accentuated/distorted.**

So when I shoot a photograph of you at 200cm distance, then your face always will be (relatively) flat - no matter if I use a 100mm lens (a [medium shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_(filmmaking)#By_field_size)) or a ultra-wide lens (more of a panoramic shot with you in it). When I change my distance to 50cm, it will look like your nose was bigger than the rest of your face - no matter if I use the same 100mm lens (which will probably lead to a nose-only shot) or a ultra-wide lens (which will now result in a medium shot).

---

Now depending on the lens in question, it might have a [barrel distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)#Radial_distortion), which means that the middle of the image gets a bit more magnified than the outer portions. While this is usually the case with wide angle lenses, it could also have a pincussion distortion (magnification is stronger towards the outer portions) - or no distortion at all.

As lenses distort the frame, so do adapters. Most professional extenders are built so they counteract the distortion of a lens (a bit) - however, with more generic equipment, it is unlikely that this is the case. Therefore, as worst case, you could end up with double the barrel distortion.

---

Lens distortion, however, usually does not affect the image as much as does the composition (distance). **Therefore, a bit more barrel distortion might still lead to less distorted looking faces than the phone's lens alone, because for the same framing, the distance camera/face will be greater.**

Comment: Ok, so short answer is really that the distortion is there, but using a clip on zoom lens allows her to increase the distance from camera to subject while keeping the same composition, and that should keep her features flatter. Got it!

Comment: @armadadrive When we talk about the lens's distortion, it might be there - or not. Perhaps it is really cleverly designed, perhaps the phone's software corrects it automatically. The **much more relevant accentuation that comes with decreasing distance** will get better with greater focal length (considering we want the same framing, e.g. a medium shot).